# Which regularly used writing scripts commonly spoken are not alphabetic?

Tags: english, phonetics

I believe Japanese and Chinese are more logographic and the rest are simply alphabetic or abugida/abjad/alphabetic.

Using [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_writing_systems) as a reference it appears their definition of an alphabetic is not as loose as others.  I believe something is alphabetic having under 50 symbols that represent its language.

Is this correct?

Comment: Some initial reading on writing systems would be a good start.

Comment: @LukeSawczak edited.  So it appears abjad/abugida are basically alphabetic with simply combining constants or symbols.

Comment: Chinese is logographic (only partially sound-encoding, and not quite predictably so); Japanese is only partly logographic: kanji are logographic, while the kanas are entirely sound-based syllabaries.

Comment: What are the mainstream languages? Also, what's your definition of "alphabetic", or is alphabet irrelevant to your question?

Comment: @user6726 maybe under 50 symbols.

Comment: So excluding Caucasian and click languages.

Comment: @jlawler if has under 50 or so symbols then it is probably loosely alphabetic.

Comment: Many click languages are over 100, or close. Most Caucasian languages I know of have over 50 consonants.

Comment: @jlawler I believe you can add it as an answer

Comment: But they're all alphabetic languages; they just have a lot of letters.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can answer this question for yourself with minimal research. I think the reason you're being downvoted is that you're making incorrect assumptions (e.g. "something is alpahabetic having under 50 symbols that represent its language") that a little effort would easily clear up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question can apparently be paraphrased as "Which regularly-used writing system uses more than 50 letters". Chinese clearly qualifies. Most logographic systems have fallen out of use. Japanese has multiple systems: there are lots of Chinese characters, and just over 50 kana, assuming that you don't count the dakuten (diacritics) and yōon, which are digraphs for *rya* etc. Although they usually present Ge'ez script as having many letters, really these can be reduced to a consonant core plus a conventionalized vowel flourish. So Japanese kana could be numbered above 50, or just at 50, depending on how strict you want to be in your criteria. Consonant conjuncts in [Devanagari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagar) can be challenging to recognize as combinations, but they mostly are (and the vowels are clearly separable). In a more reductionist view there are 33 consonants and about a half-dozen vowel marks, but [1296 CC conjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_conjuncts) which includes श्च, the combination of श and च, and some 3 and 4 consonant conjuncts like क्ष्ण्य which is क+ष+ण+य. The combination ग plus ज (g+j) is ग्ज, which is more recognizable if you remove the stick on the right side of *g*.

However, if you take too many liberties you wouldn't count Arabic *ħ χ dʒ* as different since the basic shape is the same and they is just a flourish that distinguishes the consonants. And the isolated, initial, medial, final forms of some Arabic letters are rather different, so if you count them, Arabic would have more than 50 letters. Similarly, Kabardian (written in a form of Cyrillic) could be said to have more that 50 letters, but that includes digraphs and trigraphs like <хъу> which are recognizably х+ъ+у. The answer mostly depends on your criteria for identifying a "letter". I think of á as a letter with a diacritic but in North Saami it is treated as a separate letter.

Comment: Could you elaborate Devanagari like how many character or character combinations does it have?

Comment: Check the link. Those 1296 are only the **two**-consonant combinations. There are many more possible, some rare. Japanese and Korean are much better languages for syllabic-based writing systems than Sanskrit or Hindi; they have much simpler syllables.